# visual c++ draw a good quality icon in a presubclass button

Tags: button, visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2015, dialog

As many developpers, I try to load different images on a button for different states of button (normal, hover and click). 
I started to include a icon with a **size of 64x64**

I defined my own control button with a **size of 35x35**:

```
CONTROL         "INV",IDC_SENSINV,"Button",BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_TABSTOP,75,106,35,35
```

I defined a presubclass button and in drawItem function, i get the rect, load icon and draw icon:

```
void CimageButton::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
CRect rect = lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem; //rect of 53x57 ??
UINT state = lpDrawItemStruct->itemState;

hIcon = (HICON)LoadIcon(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(i_iconeNormal)

DrawIconEx(*pDC,
    0,
    2,
    (HICON)hIcon,
    53,
    53,
    0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
}
```

My problem is the quality of drawned icon is not good and I dont understand why

- my button has a size of 35x35 and i get a rect of 53x57
- which size should be the icon (smaller or bigger than button)
- what is the way to get the best drawned icon quality

I hope to be clear, thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You'd be better off using a bitmap for your button images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `LoadImage` instead. Use the exact icon size which you want. For example 32x32. If your icon is 48x48 then put that instead, this will prevent icon resizing.

You don't need `hIcon` after it has been drawn, so destroy it to prevent resource leak.

```
HICON hIcon = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
    MAKEINTRESOURCE(i_iconeNormal), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR);

DrawIconEx(*pDC, 0, 2, hIcon, 32, 32, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
DestoryIcon(hIcon);
```

Comment: You are right, the best is to have a icon size equal to the rect for having the best quality. If you want to resize your icon, you need to take care of your icon size has same vertical and horizontal resizing coefficient.

Answer (score 0):

`LoadIcon` always loads an icon in the default size (usually 32x32). So the icon is reduced and than again expanded when drawn.

Use always `LoadImage` to retrieve an icon with a different size.
Also tread the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms648072(v=vs.85).aspx)